# Cable modem with WiFi on off switch

Tags: wifi, router

I am looking for a cable modem that has the ability to shut WiFi on and off. I need the modem to be DOCSIS 3.0 at the least. The network I’d be using this for is Spectrum. Are there models that are compatible with the requirements I have?

Searches I’ve made have turned out modems that have WiFi but no switch to turn it on or off.

Updates:
A physical button would great but access to the panel for on/off would be acceptable too. Ideally this would be one item housing both the modem and router. Setups that use both can work if none exist. For channels, my preference is 16x4 but 24x8 will si too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any 'Gateway' device (cable modem + router) and any router allow you to disable the WiFi, if my no other means, changing the wireless LAN's IP address or network name.

https://www.bestbuy.com/site/netgear-nighthawk-dual-band-ac1900-router-with-24-x-8-docsis-3-0-cable-modem-black/4403100.p?skuId=4403100
and
https://www.bestbuy.com/site/motorola-dual-band-ac1900-router-with-16-x-4-docsis-3-0-cable-modem-black/5619201.p?skuId=5619201

are immediately available from Buy More and have 24x8 channels as well as WPA2-PSK encryption and 802.11ac WiFi.

The Motorola is Spectrum-certified, whereas users of the Netgear say it does work on Spectrum.